# looking at the digits of a number in java

Tags: java

How do I know if all the digits of a 7-digit number are different?For instance, I am generating a 6-digit random number and this number is 648392. This number can be 7,8 or 13 digits. How do I check if the digits of this number are the same?

Comment: Create a string "0123456789". Remove a char at a random index and put that char into a new string. Repeat until new string has enough digits.

Comment: So for example the user types 9, and then the program should generate a 9-digit number, is that what you mean? Does your code work and give the expected result? If not, what happens instead?

Comment: If the user enters 5, I have to generate a 5-digit random number, but the digits of this number must be different. @OleV.V.

Comment: So the first thing to do is if the user enters a number greater than 10, you should issue an error message because you cannot generate a number with more than 10 different digits.

Comment: You could do it with an array. Or is it a requirement that you do this without arrays?

Comment: yes I have to do it without the array @NomadMaker

Answer (score 2):

One idea is: Generate the random number as a string. For each digit, generate it in a loop where you check whether it is already in the string, and if so, take one more turn through the loop to generate a different one. Once you have a digit that is not in the string, append it to the string.

To check whether a digit is already in the string, convert the digit itself to a string using `String.valueOf()`. Then use `String.contains()` for checking.

And before doing any of that, check that the number entered is at most 10. If you try the above with 11 or more digits, your program will run in an infinite loop because when there are already 10 different digits in the string, you won’t be able to generate a digit that is not there. So if the user enters a number greater than 10, it’s better to issue an error message from the start.

Comment: thank you I will try

Comment: Is leading zero legal? If not you'll have to check that too.

Answer (score 1):

You have a range of 10, so create an array of length 10, inside the random method, every time you get a new value, add the value to the array, and check to see if the array has that value already, if it does, rerun the method, else add it to the array and return the value.

```
    static int [] arr= new int [10];
    static int index=0;

    public static void main(String[]args)

    public static int random(int k){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int r1=0;
    for (int i=1; i<=k; i++){
        r1 = rand.nextInt(10);
    }
    //For the first Run
    if(i==0)
     {
       arr[i]=r1;
       return r1;
     }
    //Check each value against the remaning value
    for(int j=0; j<arr.length; j++){
     if(arr[j]== r1)
      { random(int k); }
      else {
       return r1;
```

Comment: thank you but I do not know array so I try to write with if else loop and method

Comment: I believe that this is an exercise and that we’re doing a mis-favour (is that a word?) when giving away working code. [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)